# UNetbootin on 32GB USB 3 Stick

Tags: boot, usb, windows-7, live-usb, unetbootin

I run a windows 7 machine, and use UNetbootin to create Ubuntu bootable live USB keys.

I have 1 key in particular that I would like to use entirely as a live Ubuntu key, so I can install some apps, etc...

What I am finding is that filesystem.squashfs is simply not big enough to install all the apps I need to install.

My Persistent storage is 10GB the stick is ntfs formatted (though I could change that)

My question is, how can I make the filesystem.squashfs bigger so I can install all the apps I need?

Yes, I've already tried installing Ubuntu directly to the stick, but it seems that it is machine specific

Comment: You should be able to just install applications, which will use the persistence storage. BUT, you are booting an NTFS formatted stick? I thought syslinux needed FAT. FAT files are limited to 4G, is your persistence a partition?  Please add more detail.

Comment: persistence is not a partition, and I was able to create and boot from it as NTFS

Comment: It looks like you're mixing technologies.  UNetbootin is great for creating LiveUSBs, but to create "an Ubuntu on a stick" you need casper-rw, not squashfs.  Did you ever follow [the official Ubuntu instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence) for making a live persistent USB stick?